# Null Pointer exception when building docker file from NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, docker, netbeans

This is a simple Maven project created with NetBeans and a simple

```
 System.out.println("hello world");
```

in the main class.

Docker is running and available as a service in NetBeans.

The Docker file is:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:latest
copy target/TestDocker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar .
CMD ["java","-jar", "TestDocker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

When building the file, the error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.printANSI(OutWriter.java:632)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.print(OutWriter.java:591)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.ErrWriter.print(ErrWriter.java:211)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.ErrWriter.println(ErrWriter.java:165)
    at org.netbeans.modules.docker.ui.build2.BuildTask.run(BuildTask.java:200)
    at org.netbeans.modules.docker.ui.build2.BuildImageWizard$1.run(BuildImageWizard.java:276)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
```

Comment: Is that your full Dockerfile? Does it have a FROM instruction?

Comment: I forgot to add the FROM line in the SA question but it was indeed there in my Docker file. Edited the question to add it.

Comment: I have created a simple hello world program with maven and your provided Dockerfile and do not get any error while building or running. I did this test on Linux with Netbeans 8.2.

Comment: and you build and run by clicking in the Netbeans GUI? (I don't get an error when working from the CLI)

Comment: Yes I did everything via the Netbeans GUI.